# PHPmyEdit: Pull table data using string value rather than set value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using PHPMyEdit, and the file generated after I ran the setup reads:

```
$opts['hn'] = 'localhost';
$opts['un'] = 'user';
$opts['pw'] = 'pass';
$opts['db'] = 'db';
$opts['tb'] = 'table_name';
```

I need it to function as such:

```
$foo = $_POST['bar'];

...

$opts['hn'] = 'localhost';
$opts['un'] = 'user';
$opts['pw'] = 'pass';
$opts['db'] = 'db';
$opts['tb'] = $foo;
```

If I run the code as such, it pulls the table data just fine, but when I try to edit, copy, etc., it reads:

> **phpMyEdit error: no table defined**.

Has anyone else been in the same situation and was able to figure out a solution?

Comment: Because on the edit page you are most probably not sending `$_POST['bar']`

Answer (score 0):

The `$opts` variable is defined in php.MyEdit.class.php file. The file generated by the setup doc is not designed to support additional '$_POST' calls. Run phpMyEditSetup.php to fill in the table name as well as all of your other database fields. You could edit the class file if you don't want to generate your php the way phpMyEdit was designed.